# Custom Model Doesn't Show Up In Dropdown List After Installing in Odoo

Tags: odoo

I have developed a new module in Odoo. I did install the module but it dose not appear in the drop down list (Installed Apps List)

[image]

Comment: Hello,
The reason why you are not seeing the menu is that you haven't given security/access rights for the menu and model you have given.

Comment: or you haven't updated app list after opening debug mode

Comment: thanks, I changed the user to a super user and it appeared.

Answer (score 0):

In the modules `__manifest__.py` make sure to set the attribute application to True to make the module show up as an application.

```
{
    'name': 'my application',
    'summary': 'this applications makes odoo awesome',
    'category': 'Custom',
    'version': '1.0',
    ...
    'application': True,
    ...
}
```

The odoo core account module is an application: [manifest](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/account/__manifest__.py)

The odoo core account_check_printing module is not an application and does not show up in apps: [manifest](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/account_check_printing/__manifest__.py)

Alternatively you can remove the default "App" filter in the Apps list view and your module should show up.